# .net API - Asynchronous requests issue

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I return an error message if the carrier status has been sold. I can't control asynchronous requests. if there are two simultaneous requests for the same carrier, I sell the carrier twice.

When you sell the carrier twice, inventory stock is deteriorating. How do I control this?

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<Result> AddCarrierToTransfer(CarrierToTransferModel carrierModel)
{
    Result result = new Result(true);
    try
    {
        var pdb = new PdbEntities();
        using (var ts = await pdb.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
        {
            var carrier = await pdb.Carrier.FindAsync(carrierModel.Id);
            if(carrier.Status == (int)CarrierStatus.Sold)
            {
                result.IsSucceed = false;
                result.Message = "Cannot add to transfer, carrier status is sold.";
                return result;
            }

            // Do other works

            await pdb.SaveChangesAsync();
            ts.Commit();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        result.IsSucceed = false;
        result.Message = e.Message;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Ex:

**This is work**

```
2019.12.13 `10:18` 1 Request For Carrier Id = 1
Result: true

2019.12.13 `10:20` 1 Request For Carrier Id = 1
Result: false
Message: "Cannot add to transfer, carrier status is sold."
```

**This is not work**

```
2019.12.13 `10:18` 1 Request For Carrier Id = 1
Result: true
2019.12.13 `10:18` 1 Request For Carrier Id = 1
Result: true
2019.12.13 `10:18` 1 Request For Carrier Id = 1
Result: true
2019.12.13 `10:18` 1 Request For Carrier Id = 1
Result: true
2019.12.13 `10:18` 1 Request For Carrier Id = 1
Result: true
```

**Expected**

```
2019.12.13 `10:18` 1 Request For Carrier Id = 1
Result: true
2019.12.13 `10:18` 1 Request For Carrier Id = 1
Result: false
Message: "Cannot add to transfer, carrier status is sold."
2019.12.13 `10:18` 1 Request For Carrier Id = 1
Result: false
Message: "Cannot add to transfer, carrier status is sold."
2019.12.13 `10:18` 1 Request For Carrier Id = 1
Result: false
Message: "Cannot add to transfer, carrier status is sold."
2019.12.13 `10:18` 1 Request For Carrier Id = 1
Result: false
Message: "Cannot add to transfer, carrier status is sold."
```

Comment: We don't really understand what you are trying to do. You need to provide more context.

Comment: `if(carrier.Status == (int)CarrierStatus.Sold)` If there are many async requests for same carrier, I don't understand whether the carrier has been sold or not. Ex. There are 5 requests for same carrier, Only 1 carrier should add to transfer and it should return error message for other 4 carriers @AthanasiosKataras

Comment: If you have many many requests, locking techniques may deteriorate performance. That makes this a non-trivial task. Maybe you want to have a look at how that's handled by big sellers like Amazon?

Comment: I will, Thank you @Fildor

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following approach. To explain it to you, there is only one thread of code that can be executing the code in between lock at any given time.

This way you control the flow and you can be certain that the first transfer has completed before the second can start.

```
static SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);  
[HttpPost]
public async Task<Result> AddCarrierToTransfer(CarrierToTransferModel carrierModel)
{
    Result result = new Result(true);
    try
   {
        await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();

            var pdb = new PdbEntities();
            using (var ts = await pdb.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
            {
                var carrier = await pdb.Carrier.FindAsync(carrierModel.Id);
                if(carrier.Status == (int)CarrierStatus.Sold)
                {
                    result.IsSucceed = false;
                    result.Message = "Cannot add to transfer, carrier status is sold.";
                    return result;
                 }

                // Do other works

                await pdb.SaveChangesAsync();
                ts.Commit();
            }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        result.IsSucceed = false;
        result.Message = e.Message;
    }
    finally {
        semaphoreSlim.Release();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Since TAP is in use, maybe a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netframework-4.8) would be preferable.

Comment: Its going to be one at a time. SemaphoreSlim is used to allow more than one thread. What would be useful would be to create lock objects per id, so that you can allow for simultaneous transfers of different items at the same time

Comment: Then you need to provide more code. I suspect that the change of inventory happens outside this asynchronous function

Comment: I give an example. Can you check question again. @AthanasiosKataras

Comment: The Problem with lock is, that it's reeentrant (which I already burnt my fingers on). So if it happens to be the case that the same thread will enter twice (because one Task is awaiting async I/O), it will pass the lock just fine. SemaphoreSlim will not.

Comment: let me try `SemaphoreSlim` @Fildor

Comment: There are also some solutions by Stephen Toub and Stephen Cleary. I don't know if they are still "state of the art" though. The one from Stephen C. is from 2014 ...

Comment: I think this is more up to date: https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx (See especially section "AsyncLock"). Must have been directed to an older repo, before. Nuget: [Nito.AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx)

Comment: @Fidor You are quite right. I changed the code with semaphoreSlim.

Answer (score 0):

What you're experiencing is a race condition. You need to limit your sell functionality to one at a time. Either implement some sort of queuing mechanism for sell functionality(best option in my opinion) or use a simple `lock` statement in your code.

What this will achieve is allow the first sell instruction to be processed while the other waits. When the second instruction comes in at the same time it then will receive the error that it has already been sold. You might need to enhance your code to accommodate the check to see that it has been sold.

Comment: can you give me an example for `queuing mechanism `

Comment: Queuing is more of a design pattern, not as easy as a simple code example. Have a look here https://michaelscodingspot.com/c-job-queues/

Comment: I cannot use this pattern on rest api. How can i response then?

Comment: Use the lock or semaphore then as suggested by myself and others here